# What are the benefits of closing doors inside my shelter?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

I can close doors in my shelter but I don't know if there are any advantages in it. Closing doors in other locations have obvious benefits for stealth gameplay.

Do closed doors help with heating or prevent raids or have any other use?

Answer (score 1):

I think it does affect heating, but mainly, having doors open means that intruders can get through the building quicker.

Comment: do you have any proofs? This seems logical, yes, but I cannot find any proofs or tests done

Comment: I have been looking of TWOM Wikia. Apparently, heating isn't really affected that much by closing the door. It only has a negligable effect. From what I have seen, its better for when you are being raided (NPC cant see you->takes longer->you can sneak up on them), or for scavenging (NPC detected you ->slowed by door ->cant see through door )